# Matlab: How to remove the error of non-existent field

Tags: matlab

I am getting an error when running matlab code. Here I am trying to use one of the outputs of previous code as input to my new code.

```
??? Reference to non-existent field 'y1'.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

A good practice might be to check if the field exists before accessing it:

```
if isfield( s, 'y1' )
    % s.y1 exists - you may access it
    s.y1
else
    % s.y1 does not exist - what are you going to do about it?
end
```

To take Edric's comment into account, another possible way is

```
try 
    % access y1
    s.y1
catch em
    % verify that the error indeed stems from non-existant field
    if strcmp(em.identifier, 'MATLAB:nonExistentField')
         fprintf(1, 'field y1 does not exist...\n');
    else
         throw( em ); % different error - handle by caller?
    end
end
```

Comment: Sadly, it's actually faster to use try/catch here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the command **load** to load data from file(s)?
if yes, this function overwrite your current variables, therefore, they become non-existent, so when you call, it instead of using:

```
load ('filename');
```

use:

```
f=load ('filename');
```

now, to refer to any variable inside the loaded file use f.varname, for
example if there is a network called net saved within the loaded data you may use it like:

```
a = f.net(fv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first explain my situation and then give the solution.

- I first save a variable `op`, it is a **struct** , its name is `coef.mat`;
- I load this variable using `coef = load( file_path, '-mat')`;
- In a new function, I pass variable `coef` to it as a parameter, at here, the error **Reference to non-existent field** pops out.

My solution:

- Just replace `coef` with `coef.op`, then pass it to the function, it will work.

So, I think the reason behind is that: the **struct** was saved as a variable, when you use `load` and want to **acess** the origin variable, you need point it out directly using `dot(.)` operation, you can directly open the variable in Matlab workspace and find out what it wraps inside the variable.

In your case, if your *the outputs of previous code* is a struct(It's my guess, but you haven't pointed out) and you saved it as `MyStruct`, you load it as `MyInput = load(MyStruct)`, **then when use it as function's parameter, it should be** `MyInput.y1`.

Hops it would work!

Answer (score 0):

At first load it on command window and observe the workspace window. You can see the structure name. It will work by accessing **structure name**. Example:

```
lm=load('data.mat');
disp(lm.SAMPLE.X);
```

Here SAMPLE is the structure name and X is a member of the structure